# Symfony 2 - Login programmatically

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have a user object, and I would like to do something like:

```
Auth::login($user) or Auth::attempt($user->getEmail()
```

or

```
$user->getPassword())
```

Which one is the better way? How do I do login with Symfony2?

**EDIT - Does not work yet**

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "user_area", $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

return $this->redirectToRoute('panel');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called "login a user programmatically" and it's done like this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "firewall_name", $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);
```

It's not possible to explain all the concepts related to the Symfony Security system in this answer, so please read the [security chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) of the Symfony book or the [security tutorials](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html) from the official Symfony documentation.

Comment: The `$user` object must be a real user (usually obtained from the database) and it must implement the `UserInterface`. The `firwall_name` value must be changed to the name of your main firewall in `app/config/security.yml` file. The `$user->getRoles()` must return an `array` even when the user (at minimum it should return `array('ROLE_USER')`).